# How to print url of blog tags in drupal

Tags: url, drupal

How to print url alias of blog tags in Drupal?
`uri.value` is not working

```
{% for item in node.field_tags %}
 {{ item.entity.uri.value }} {{ item.entity.name.value }}
{% endfor %}

{{ item.entity.uri.value }} # this isn't working
```

Comment: What is the machine name of your "uri" field? Is it `field_uri`?

Comment: i want to print the url alias of tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `path()` function like below to print url alias of the tags:

```
{% for item in node.field_tags %}
  {{ path('entity.taxonomy_term.canonical', { 'taxonomy_term': item.entity.id() }) }}
{% endfor %}
```

or `url()` if you want an absolute url:

```
{% for item in node.field_tags %}
  {{ url('entity.taxonomy_term.canonical', { 'taxonomy_term': item.entity.id() }) }}
{% endfor %}
```